# What does stand for named -t option?

Tags: bind, named

I've read that by using `named -t` I can chroot to specified directory.
My question is what does stand for the `-t`?

Comment: Probably stands for "chrooT", given that `-c` is taken by "-c config_file"

Comment: Thanks I'd learn with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try reading the `man` page.

If you type `man named` into your shell and scroll down it should give you a decent description of what the -t command does.

In this case it outputs the following:

```
-t directory
 Chroot to directory after processing the command line arguments,
           but before reading the configuration file.
```

Hope this helps.